# local php.ini file does not load in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, php5, php.ini, web-platform-installer

I have PHP 5.3.5 installed on IIS 7 which I installed through WebPI (Web Platform Installer).  I would like to have some global settings controlled on a site by site basis but I am unable to have the changes take.  For example, by default register_globals = Off, but I want one site to be able to set register_globals = On.

I create a php.ini file with simply the following two lines, and save it to the root of the site:

```
[php]
register_globals = On
```

When I run phpinfo() from another .php file to just inspect the settings, the global and local setting for register_globals shows up as Off.  I expect the Global setting to be Off and the Local to be On.  I also notice that" Additional .ini files parsed" = (none) which gives me the impression that it just simply isn't loading the php.ini file in the root of the site.

I have not changed any settings after I installed PHP through WebPI, so the global php.ini file is set to whatever the defaults are.  Anyone have an idea what's going on or what to try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This might help](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/745/enable-per-site-php-configuration-on-iis-7-and-iis-60/) if you need the full php.ini file, although @Constantine has a much simpler solution if you don't.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [ini_set](https://www.php.net/ini_set) . with this function you can modify global settings from php.ini for particular page or all website.